# How to handle unchecked checkboxes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I have an edit form with several checkboxes in Laravel. When I check the boxes and update the record, it works correctly, but if I uncheck the box it doesn't return any value so the record doesn't update and the value remains true in the database.

How can I handle unchecked checkboxes in Laravel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489519/how-to-pass-checkbox-value-0-if-not-checked-and-1-if-checked-using-array-laravel/60831005#60831005

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [mozilla documentation on checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox):

> If a checkbox is unchecked when its form is submitted, there is no value submitted to the server to represent its unchecked state (e.g. value=unchecked); the value is not submitted to the server at all.

So, the following will do the trick:

```
$isChecked = $request->has('checkbox-name');
```

Comment: [Here's a great YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGmtvdGpvuM) which explains and demos this, along with the hidden field method.  It's a trade off between writing a more complex `->update()` method or being able to keep a simple `->update($request->all());` in the controller while adding a prefix in the form.

Answer (score 30):

Place a hidden textbox with a 0 value **before** the checkbox so a 0 value is sent into the POST array.

```
{{Form::hidden('value',0)}}
{{Form::checkbox('value')}}
```

Comment: my controller code for update is `$module->update($request->only($module->getFillable()));`, so this is the only thing that works for me.

Comment: Brilliant solution 

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="1">
```

if checkbox is checked => server get "1"

otherwise => server get "0"

Answer (score 6):

The best way I can think of is using ternary and null coalesce PHP operators:

```
$request->checkbox ? 1 : 0 ?? 0;
```

This will return `1` if checked, `0` if not checked or not available.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML forms when you check checkbox it's arrived with the POST,

and you don't check it ... so it's not exists at all in the POST.

so you need to check if it's exists ...

```
if($request->has('input-name')) {
     $value = $request->input('input-name')
}
else {
     $value = "put default value (false)";
}
.... 
do your stuff with the value
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just check if the input checkbox exists, if it is exists, $value equals input checkbox value, and if it doesnt exists that means checkbox is unchecked, so $value is false.
You also have to add a form request to be sure that the input contains a boolean

```php
$value = $request->has('checkbox') ? $request->input('checkbox') : false
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to contribute with my example
(In this context laravel 9.x and bootstrap 5 are used, but the logic behind is the same as other aswers, only that this will not send two fields with the same name, because this can produce ambiguous results depending of wich fields will be read last or first by PHP interpreter)

in my validation rule I have something like this (my field name is 'active'):

```
'active'=>'required|boolean|in:1,0'
```

So in the blade rendering part I wrote this:

```html
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input id="active" type="hidden" name="active" value="@if(!empty($record->active)) 1 @else 0 @endif">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" @checked($record->active) onclick="document.getElementById('active').value=this.checked?1:0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Is Active</label>
</div>
```

In this way, always a 0 or a 1 will be sent

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->checkbox ?? $request->merge(['checkbox' => $value]);
```

If $request->checkbox is null it is replaced by the proper $value (i.e. 0) in the $request, the you can just "update" the usual way.