# How to pass Checkbox value 0 if not checked and 1 if checked using array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have form with checkbox

```
   @foreach($accounts as $acc)
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="account[{{ $acc->id }}]" @if($acc->published) checked @endif>
   @endforeach
```

How I can pass 0 value when checkbox is not checked?

My controller:

```
public function updateMon(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'account' => 'required|array',
        'account.*' => 'integer'
    ]);

    foreach($account as $acc => $val) {
        dd($val); //how get 0?
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remember, checkboxes are not actually sent in the request if they are not checked. So you basically have to test for its existance using a `isset()`. If it exists, you can capture the value, if it does not exist, then default the value to whatever you want the Off setting to be

Comment: I think you are also missing a closing `"` for your `name` attribute

Comment: If the input is not checked it will not be sen through.  So.. `if(!isset($yourval)){$yourval = 0;}` although more commonly used in Laravel for these situations would be a ternary operator.

Comment: Ok but validation?

Comment: Is this Boolean?  Why not do `$yourval = (!isset($yourval)) ? 0 : 1 ; OR $yourval = (!isset($yourval)) ? false : true ; OR $yourval = (isset($yourval)) ? true : false;` then no need for validation as you are setting it.

Comment: But array how send? If checkbox not checked..

Comment: [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

checkboxes are only posted when they are checked, so in controller you can use this fragment

```
public function updateMon(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'account' => 'required|array',
        'account.*' => 'integer'
    ]);


    $myVar = isset($request->account[0]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@foreach($accounts as $acc)
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="account[{{ $acc->id }}]">
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="account[{{ $acc->id }}]" @if($acc->published) checked @endif>
@endforeach
```

In controller

```
public function updateMon(Request $request) {
$request->validate([
    'account' => 'required|array',
    'account.*' => 'boolean'
]);

foreach($account as $acc => $val) {
    dd($val); //that returns 0 if not checked
}
}
```

If checked on checkbox than it gets value = 1
if not checked on checkbox gets value =0

Answer (score 1):

Just add hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden"  name="account[{{$acc->id }}]" value="0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel Collective,

```
@foreach($accounts as $acc)

{{ Form::hidden('account['. $acc->id .']', false) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('display['.$acc->id.']', true,$acc->published ? true : false) }}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Request::macro('checkbox', function ($key, $checked = 1, $notChecked = 0) {
     return $this->input($key) ? $checked : $notChecked;
});
```

And use it like:

```
$model->property = $request->checkbox('input_name');
```

or

```
$model->property = $request->checkbox('input_name', 'yes', 'no');
```

depending on what values you need to store. You don't need do validate, you just need to check if the param is received.

I had to deal with the same issue, and I've tried many methods and I've found this one to be the most elegant.