# Error retrieving a checked Checkbox in Laravel as a boolean

Tags: laravel, checkbox, boolean

I'm a bit new to `laravel`  and I'm working on a `laravel` application which has a `checkbox` field which should have a `boolean` value of `1` when the user checks the `checkbox`, and `0` when the `checkbox` is unchecked.

I want to retrieve the boolean value as either 1 or 0 and save in a db.

Please assist?

**View**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2c.getplans') }}" id="travel_form"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="check-now {{ $errors->has('spouse') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <h1 class="cover-travel">I am travelling with</h1>
        <label class="spouse-me">
            <h1 class="pumba">Spouse</h1>
            <input id="spouse" type="checkbox" name="spouse">
            <span class="checkmark" name="spouse"></span>
        </label>
        @if ($errors->has('spouse'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('spouse') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="form-b3c"> Get Plans</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
 public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {

        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'WithSpouse' => (\Input::has('spouse')) ? 1 : 0;
        ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle unchecked checkboxes in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800663/how-to-handle-unchecked-checkboxes-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st way is send correct value from frontend side**

you can add jquery or javascript at frontend side on change event of checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />

<script>
$(document).on('change','#myCheckbox',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#myCheckbox').val(1);
    }else{
       $('#myCheckbox').val(0);
    }
});
</script>
```

at your backend side , now you can check :

```
 $yourVariable=$request->input('checkbox');
```

**2nd way is only check at your backend**

you will get your `checkbox value=on` if it checked

```
if($request->input('checkbox')=='on'){
   $yourVariable=1;
}else{
   $yourVariable=0;
  }
```

you can use ternary condition as well , like :

```
$yourVariable = $request->input('checkbox')=='on' ? 1:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to validate a checkbox value. because if its `checked` it sends the value of `on`, and if it's not `checked` it doesn't send anything.

So, all you need is that get whether the check box is checked or not, you can do as follow.

to retrieve the boolean value of the checkbox,

**Controller**

```
// since you haven't provide any codes in the controller what
// are you gonna do with this value,
// I will juts catch it to a variable.

$isChecked = $request->spouse == 'on'
```

Comment: With what you have said, I don't think you would need to even check if `== 'on'`. Just check the variable to see if true.

Comment: but `$isChecked = $request->spause;` is not right ok? because if it's checked you get the value 'on', you you need is `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Tharaka,, Thanks for help,, What I want to do is have a logic such as a ternary operator  whereby if the checkbox is checked the value should be 1 if not checked the value should be 0.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Then you can pass variable as `$isChecked = (bool) $request->spouse`.

Comment: You don't need to be that complicated @Pweb, this is the simplest. this is equal to `$request->spause == 'on' ? true : false ;`

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve checkbox value from request as boolean:

```php
$yourModel->with_spouse = (bool) $request->spouse;
```

If checkbox is checked then it's value (`on` by default) will be passed to request and casting non-empty string to boolean will give you `true`. If checkbox is not checked then `spouse` key won't be passed to request at all, so `$request->spouse` will return `null`. Casting `null` to boolean will result in `false` (in PHP `true` is int `1` and `false` is int `0`, which is exactly what you want).

Comment: ,, Thanks duly noted.. Actually am saving my data in an API endpoint via POST request... The endpoint of the URL displays data format as `"WithSpouse":"0",` so if I save as null it throws an error,, Kindly assist how I can convert **null** to **zero** or **true** to **1**

Comment: @Pweb Just add another type cast to int: `(int)(bool) "on"` is 1. `(int)(bool) null` is 0. So you can write `(int)(bool) $request->spouse`. Explanation: it will type cast from right to left, so first it will convert to boolean (true/false) and then to int (1/0).