# How can I update the value if it's null in Laravel with fill?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page with a lot of checkboxes. The default value for these is "null". However, when I update a checkbox and put it to "true", I am not able to put it back into null even if I leave the field empty. I would want to do that if the checkbox is in the form but not checked, I still have "key" => null in my data, in order to fill my model with the empty values.

Here is my form, request and controller.

```
// EXAMPLE OF ONE INPUT
<input id="permis_de_conduire_international_1" type="checkbox" name="permis_de_conduire_international" value="1">
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StorePostRequestRegisterStep4 extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'agent_de_securite' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'investigation' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'transport_de_valeur' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'serrurier' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'technicien_camera' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'port_d_arme' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'arme_a_feu_a_autorisation_restreinte' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'permis_de_conduire' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'vehicule_de_randonnee' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'poids_lourds' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'vehicule_d_urgence' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'permis_de_conduire_international' => 'nullable|boolean',
          'permis_moto' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'permis_autobus' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'autre_permis' => 'nullable|array',
            'autre_permis.*' => 'required|string'
        ];
    }
}
```

```
    public function update(StorePostRequestRegisterStep4 $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $pro = Pro::find($request->user()->id);
        $pro->fill($data);
        $pro->save();

        return redirect()->route('register-step4.edit');
    }
```

How can I set to "null" if the box is not checked?

Comment: That's not how HTML forms work. If a checkbox is not checked, it's not submitted.

Comment: @miken32 is there a way to submit it anyway? a way in my Laravel code in the request to check that if it’s not there to fill it with a null value? something like that

Comment: Yes, "check that if it’s not there to fill it with a null value." A simple `if` statement will suffice.

Comment: One suggestion in the linked duplicate will take the work out of the controller and put it in the view: a hidden input with same name and value 0. The later input will always get sent so you can receive either 0 or 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800664/1255289

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set it manually

```
$pro->permis_de_conduire_international = $request->get('permis_de_conduire_international');
```

between your fill and save. The default return for `get` is null, so will set the value to null if the box is not checked, and thus is not in the request.

Comment: I hoped that I wouldn’t have to do that for all the fields manually but thanks!